# Pass multiple parameters with trigger and JSON call

Tags: jquery, json

I've got two variables that I am passing to a JSON call and triggering a custom event.
The JSON call works fine but if I try to add additional parameters I want to pass to my custom
event all I get is "undefined" when I try to call them. So if I try to log **obj.zipCode** 
I get an undefined error. Am I doing something wrong here or not understanding the trigger data 
parameters? Please include code samples were applicable I learn more that way.

```
var zipCode;
var userName;

zipCode = $("#zip").val();
userName = $("#user").val();

$.getJSON('/bin/services/' + zipCode + userName, function(data, status){ 
 $(document).trigger('nbcStores.gotData', [data,zipCode,userName]);
});

$(document).on('nbcStores.gotData', function(e, obj) {
  console.log("RESULTS" + obj.zipCode);
  console.log("RESULTS" + obj.userName); 
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just log `obj`, what does it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the request wrong.

```
var settings = {
    url: "/bin/services/",
    data: {zipcode:zipCode, username:userName},
    success: function(data,status){...},
};
$.getJSON(settings.url, settings.data, settings.success);

//what i usually use:
$.ajax(settings);
```

i defined the keys which are being looked for as zipcode and username, but you might want to assign it as something else.

see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

the optional data param is an object, so in settings, i defined data as an object contained 2 key->value pairs.